# Hyperlinks is not working right for search result titles

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to show search results from two tables. I have used union to put them together. Right now they work, when I search for something and matches, it shows up from both of the tables but I am having problem with the hyperlinks. Right now, for the search results it is always redirecting to grants individual when clicked on the title even for the results from art table. Please help, how do I make sure it goes to the right details page.

Controller

```
function searchResult() {
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']    =   $this->products_model->searchResult($keyword);
    $this->load->view($this->header)
    $this->load->view('searchresults.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

View

```
<br>
<table>
<?php if (!$results){ ?>

  <h1> No results found. </h1>

<?php 
}

else { ?>
 <h2> Search Results </h2>
<?php

foreach($results as $row){ ?>

<br>
  <table class="table">
 <tr>
    <td><h2><a href="<?=  base_url()?>product/grantindividual/<?=$row->id?>"><?php echo $row->title?> 
  </h2></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><h2><a href="<?=  base_url()?>product/artcallindividual/<?=$row->id?>"><?php echo $row- 
    >title?></h2></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }

 }
?>
<br>
```

Comment: Posting controller code (product) may helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a column to differentiate the results, no need for adding an actual column in table itself, use dummy columns

Change this

```
$this->db->select($this->db->escape('v_grants') .  ' AS source, id, Title');
```

To

```
$this->db->select($this->db->escape('v_grants') .  " AS source, id, Title, 'grant' as type ");
```

Change this

```
$this->db->select($this->db->escape('v_art_call') . ', id, Title');
```

To

```
$this->db->select($this->db->escape('v_art_call') . ", id, Title, 'art' as type ");
```

Then you can easily use if-else statement to display the proper row (grant/art)

```
<table class="table">

    foreach($results as $row){ ?>
        if($row->type == 'grant'){ ?>

                <tr>
                 <td><h2><a href="<?=base_url()?>product/grantindividual/<?=$row->id?>"><?php echo $row->title?> 
                    </h2></a>
                 </td>
                </tr>

        <?php }elseif($row->type == 'grant') { ?>

                <tr>
                  <td><h2><a href="<?=base_url()?>product/artcallindividual/<?=$row->id?>"><?php echo $row->title?></h2></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: I am trying to show both table result with one keyword, I have tried this and it only shows result from one table.   Edit: Got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a condition to differentiate the items from two tables.

```
<br>
<table>
<?php if (!$results){ ?>

  <h1> No results found. </h1>

<?php 
}

else { ?>
 <h2> Search Results </h2>
<?php

foreach($results as $row){ ?>

<?php
    if(!empty($row->source)){
        $url = base_url()."product/grantindividual".$row->id;
    }else{
        $url = base_url()."product/artcallindividual".$row->id;
    }
?>

<br>
  <table class="table">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?=$url?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></a>    
            </h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<?php }

 }
?>
<br>
```

Comment: do `print_r($row)` in the `If` `else` where `$url` is being set so you know if the if conditions separating the results from two tables.

what you get in `print_r($url)`,  why is it not working ? what do you mean ?